# Can't use resources defined in Window.Resources

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF project with a Window. I've added a style to the resources for that window and I'm trying to use that style on a component, but the resource can't be found!

I believe the syntax is as basic as it can be, and also the same as numerous examples I've seen online:

```
<Window x:Class="MyView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Name="ComponentsListItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <!-- Some styles -->            
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComponentsListItem}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I'm compiling I get an error on `{StaticResource ComponentsListItem}` that says

> The resource "ComponentsListItem" could not be resolved

I have also tried putting the style into a `<ResourceDictionary>` so that it looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Name="ComponentsListItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <!-- Some styles -->            
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

But that gives exactly the same error message on the exact same place.

What is going on here? Why can't I use `ComponentsListItem`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't I use ComponentsListItem

That's because you are using `x:Name` but styles are defined by using `x:Key`.

Use this and it will work fine

```
<Style x:Key="ComponentsListItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <!-- Some styles -->            
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks! See, I know there was something I had to have overlooked! :)  And, well... https://media.giphy.com/media/7ZAAheHTKwVi0/giphy.gif

Comment: I will, but you answered to quickly. I have to wait a couple more minutes until I can accept :)